# JPA / Hibernate cascade deleting while removing in ManyToOne relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have big problem with cascade remowing with @ManyToOne. I have two classes : User (from "one" side) and Adress (from "many" side), my problem is:

-when deleting Adress entity that is associated with User (User of course has many associated Adress), not only one Adress record is deleted from database, but his owner = User ass well. More over - all Adresses that  was associated with this User are deleted too :(

-so, this is not what I expected, can anyone tell me, what mistake do I do?

User class

```
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Column(name="id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

private Set<Adress> adresses;   

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     public Set<Adress> getAdresses() {
         return adresses;
     }
     ...
}
```

Unit class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="unit")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="unit_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Unit implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

Adress class

```
@DiscriminatorValue("adr")
public class Adress extends Unit implements Serializable {

     private User user;

     @ManyToOne 
     @JoinColumn(name="adress_id")
     public User getUser(){
         return user;
     }
     ...

}
```

Part of AdressDaoImpl class :

```
    public void delete(Adress adress) {
        Adress mergedWithContextAdress = entityManager.merge(adress);
        entityManager.remove(mergedWithContextAdress);
        logger.info("Adress removed.");
    }
```

parto of AdressDaoTest class:

```
    Adress adress = adressDao.findById(1);
    adressDao.delete(adress);
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you're doing the delete?

Comment: Do you have any XML mapping files, or are you only using annotations?

Comment: I have no XML, only annotations are used.

Comment: This code looks fine, so the problem must be with a part of the code that you are not showing. Are you doing other operations as part of the same transaction? Do you have `@Id` fields in your entities? If you do please show them.

Comment: Well, i did some simplifications earlier. As You can see, Address inherits from Unit along with it's Id field.

Comment: In the `Adress` class, why is the `JoinColumn` for `getUser()` called `adress_id`? I think it should be called something like `user_id`. This may not be the cause of your problem but it is very confusing. Also (unrelated note) make sure that `Adress` implements both `equals()` and `hashCode()` since it participates in a collection.

Comment: David, thanks for help, and your time ( I know it's precious ). I solved the problem. I had one more ManyToMany relation with some other table, and unluckyly i didn't see the problem. Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
  Adress adress = adressDao.findById(1);
  adress.setUser(null);   //Set null reference before remove
  adressDao.delete(adress);
```

Just a comment it should be address not address XD.

Comment: It's still removing associated User with rest of the Addresses (associated with the User) :(